# How to filter columns with multiple levels in shiny datatables?

Tags: r, filter, shiny, datatable, factors

I am trying to create a series of checklist boxes to filter columns in a data table in a Shiny app. I have created a function to parse the individual levels of the column however when I try to filter the column using a logical vector only single levels of the multi factor column (CONSEQUENCE) are filtered (rows with multiple factors for CONSEQUENCE are not filtered).
Here is an example of a column (CONSEQUENCE) with multiple levels:

[image]

My code:

```
library(dplyr)
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(DT)

parse_levels <- function(var) {
  concat_levels <- paste0(unique(var), collapse=", ")
  # split the strings
  parsed_levels <- unlist(strsplit(concat_levels, ', '))
  uniq_levels <- unique(parsed_levels)
  return(uniq_levels)
}

filter_variables <- function(var, in_val){
  if (is.factor(var)) {
    var %in% in_val
  } else if (is.character(var)) {
    # multiple levels create a list of logical vector
     list_log <- sapply(in_val, function(x){
      grepl(x, var)
    })
     apply(list_log, 1, any)
  } else {
    # in case neither return TRUE
    TRUE
  }
}

ui <- fluidPage(
  uiOutput("filters_ui"),
  textOutput("text"),
  DT::DTOutput("table")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  filters <- reactive({
    filter_variables(df$CONSEQUENCE, input$csq)
  })
  
  output$filters_ui <- renderUI({
    tagList(
      checkboxGroupInput("csq", "csq", choices=parse_levels(df$CONSEQUENCE), 
                         selected = parse_levels(df$CONSEQUENCE))
    )
  })
  output$table <- renderDataTable({
    df %>% select(CLNSIG, CONSEQUENCE) %>% filter(filters())})
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

when I try to run the code I get this error:

```
Warning: Error in filter: Problem while computing `..1 = filters()`.
Caused by error in `apply()`:
! dim(X) must have a positive length
```

Output of `dput(head(df,10))`:

```
structure(list(CLNSIG = c(NA, "Uncertain significance", "Likely benign", 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "Pathogenic/Likely pathogenic"), CONSEQUENCE = c("stop gained, frameshift", 
"missense", "missense", "frameshift", "frameshift", "frameshift", 
"stop gained", "missense", "frameshift", "splice region, synonymous"
)), row.names = c(NA, 10L), class = "data.frame")
```

Update - I have managed to remove the error using map and reduce like this

```
map(function(x){grepl(x, df$CONSEQUENCE)}) %>% reduce(~.x|.y)
```

in place of

```
...
list_log <- sapply(in_val, function(x){
      grepl(x, var)
    })
     apply(list_log, 1, any)
...
```

However, the multiple-level consequences are still not filtered properly e.g. "synonymous"

Comment: can you show `dput(head(df, 10))` for testing

Comment: The `apply(list_log, 1, any)` step works when the `list_log` is a matrix/data.frame.   Based on the `sapply`, code, it can return list or matrix (as `simplify = TRUE` by default) depending on whether it have unequal number of elements or not

Comment: @akrun thanks for your reply. I have replaced the apply/ apply code with map and reduce functions, which has removed the error but the filtering is still not working.